# Is there a difference between a copy constructor with an argument type of `const T &` and of type `const T<U> &`?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, copy-constructor

As of C++11, `std::allocator` defines three constructors that are roughly equivalent to those in the following class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class allocator {
public:
    constexpr allocator() noexcept = default;

    constexpr allocator(const allocator &other) noexcept = default;

    template<typename U>
    constexpr allocator(const allocator<U> &other) noexcept {};
};
```

The first is a default constructor, and the second is a copy constructor - pretty standard stuff. However, the third constructor confuses me quite a bit. It appears to technically be a specialization of the copy constructor? And if that is the case, would the second constructor ever even be called? Is `= default` required? How does the compiler know to provide a default implementation for the third constructor?

Comment: The second overload is a better match than the third when the argument is `allocator<T>` (when the function template argument is the same as the class template argument). In other words, if `U` would be the same as `T` then the second overload is a better match.

Comment: The third overload won't be defined to be `{}`. The compiler doesn't and shouldn't `= default` it because it isn't a [Special Member Function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Special_member_functions) that can be defaulted. It needs a definition. Edit : I guess you could `= delete` is and not define it, though that is probably not useful.

Comment: In your second function, `allocator` (without an explicit template argument) implies `allocator<T>`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Sorry, what are you trying to say? I understand that true `= default` implementations are reserved for special member functions. However, it seems the compiler replaces `{}` with some kind of pseudo-copy constructor. I suppose I'm trying to ask when/where/how/why this happens.

Comment: @QuaternionsRock I don't know where that empty brace pair comes from. The equivalent constructor for a real `std::allocator` is not defined to be `{}`. You may have added that yourself while creating this question. Edit : On second thought since `std::allocator` is stateless, the converting constructor very well might be defined to be empty since there is no state to copy or convert, though I don't think this is required. In any case, the compiler doesn't replace `{}` with anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It [the third constructor] appears to technically be a specialization of the copy constructor?

It is not a copy constructor at all.  It is actually a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) instead.

> would the second constructor ever even be called?

If an `allocator<T>` object is used to construct another `allocator<T>` object, then the second constructor will be used, yes. For example:

```cpp
allocator<int> a1;
allocator<int> a2(a1);
```

But, if a different `allocator<U>` object is used to construct an `allocator<T>` object, where `U` is not the same type as `T`, then the third constructor will be used.  For example:

```cpp
allocator<short> a1;
allocator<int> a2(a1);
```

> Is `= default` required?

Only if you want the compiler to auto-generate an implementation.  Otherwise, you have to provide one yourself.

> How does the compiler know to provide a default implementation for the third constructor?

Everything between `{}` in a constructor's body is user-defined.  If there is no `{}` then you need to use `= default` (or `= delete`) instead.

In a *non-deleted* constructor, the compiler always [default-initializes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) each class member, unless specified otherwise in the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) - which the 3rd constructor does not have.

Comment: Thanks for this. So my most recent understanding is that the third constructor is required to allow conversion from an allocator of another type, and its body just happens to be empty because `std::allocator` doesn't require any initialization. On the other hand, the second constructor is required to ensure that the compiler also creates a (presumably more efficient?) copy constructor for the case where T and U are the same. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

This template constructor

```
template<typename U>
constexpr allocator(const allocator<U> &other) noexcept {};
```

is not a copy constructor.

Copy constructor is a non-template member function of a class.

This template constructor is selected when `std::is_same_v<T, U>` is equal to false.