# Do function templates have a lower priority than functions of the same resolved type?

Tags: c++

This is closely related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108401/is-there-a-difference-between-a-copy-constructor-with-an-argument-type-of-const), but I thought it distinct enough to warrant another post.

This is a fairly pure form of the ambiguity to which I am referencing:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Class {
public:
    Class() = default;

    template<typename U>
    Class(Class<U> &) {}
};
```

This class has two potentially conflicting constructors of note: the implicit copy constructor, and the rebinding constructor template. Take the following example:

```cpp
Class<int> foo{};
Class<int> bar{foo};
```

In this case, the resolved type of the rebinding constructor template would be `Class<int>(Class<int> &)` - the same signature as the implicit copy constructor!

Does the C++ standard specify which constructor would take priority, or is it implementation-defined?

As an addendum, do special member functions (such as the copy constructor) receive special treatment in these scenarios? i.e., would the scenario

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    T x, y;

    Vector foo(Vector &other) {
        ...
    }

    template<typename U>
    Vector foo(Vector<U> &other) {
        ...
    }
};

...

Vector<int> vec1{1, 2};
Vector<int> vec2{3, 4};
auto fooVec = vec1.foo(vec2);
```

behave differently than the first example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177739/what-are-the-rules-for-choosing-from-overloaded-template-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a template specialization and a regular function, the regular function is considered better then the specialization if everything else is equal (same signature).  This is covered in [[over.match.best.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.best#general-2)

> Given these definitions, a viable function F 1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F 2 if for all arguments i, ICS i ( F 1 ) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICS i ( F 2 ) , and then
>
> - [...]
> - F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization, or, if not that,

This means that in your first case, the default compiler generated copy constructor will not be used.  The reason is that the signature of the default is `Class(Class<int> const &)`, while the template will specialize to `Class(Class<int>&)`.  Since it doesn't need to do a const qualification, it is a better match.

Your second example will use the non-template version, as both calls will resolve to `Vector<int> foo(Vector<int> &)` , and since they match, the non template version is used.

Comment: The compiler generated copy c'tor accepts a const qualified reference. I believe the first example would not use it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Good spot.  Answer updated.